# how does $p | (a^2 + b^2)$ force $p | b^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question that reads:

if $p | a$ and $p|(a^2+b^2)$, then $p | b$.

In the solution menu it reads:

since $p|a$, $p|a^2$. Now $p|a^2$ and $p|(a^2+b^2)$ forces $p|b^2$. we can conclude that $p|b$.
I honestly have no idea how $p|(a^2+b^2)$ can give you $p|b^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$p|a^2$ means there exists an integer $n$ such that $np=a^2$. Similarly, $p|(a^2+b^2)$ means there exists an integer $m$ such that $mp=a^2+b^2$. Subtracting the two gives $(m-n)p = b^2$.

Comment: $p|a$ implies $p|a^2$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $p \mid x$ and $p \mid y$ then $p \mid x-y$. So

$$p \mid a^2+b^2-a^2=b^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$p|a$ is equivalent to $a \equiv 0 \mod p$

if $a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 \mod p$ and $a \equiv 0 \mod p$ then $a^2 \equiv 0 \mod p$ hence $b^2 \equiv 0 \mod p$ so $b \equiv 0 \mod p$.